# recurrence of a dynamical system on a compact space

Tags: convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, compactness, ergodic-theory

I have a question to an exercise which was already posted (but I'm not allowed to comment it).

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145005/poincare-recurrence-theorem-and-convergence-on-compact-metric-spaces?answertab=active#tab-top

"Let $X$ be a compact metric space with metric $d$, endow $X$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and a probability measure $\mu$. Let $T\colon X\to X$ be a continuous map which is $\mu$-preserving. Then for $\mu$-almost every $x\in X$ there is a sequence $n_k\to\infty$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $T^{n_k}x\to x$ as $k\to\infty$."

I don't understand this proof given in this thread:

"Let $\mathcal P_1,\mathcal P_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of refining partitions of decreasing diameter (converging to 0) of $X$. Let $\delta_n$ be the diameter of $\mathcal P_n$. Let $\mathcal P_n(x)$ be the element of $\mathcal P_n$ containing $x$.
For $\mu$-a.e. $x$, $\mu(\mathcal P_n(x))\ne 0$."

Define $A:=\{x:\mu(P_n(x))=0\}$ => $B\subset\cup_{x \in A}(P_n(x))$.
Now I can just deduce $\mu(A)=0$ if A is countable.

"Now the Poincaré recurrence theorem applies to each element (with positive measure) of $\mathcal P_n$, saying that for almost every $z\in B\in\mathcal P_n$, $z$ returns to $B$ infinitely often. Hence there exist infinitely many $k^{(n)}_i$ such that $d(T^{k^{(n)}_i}z,z)\le \delta_n$. Let the union of the exceptional sets for each $B$ in $\mathcal P_n$ be $E_n$. 
Let $E$ be the union of the $E_n$. Then $E$ has measure 0."

I don't see why $\mu(E_n)=0$ … it's clear that the measure of the exceptional set for every B is 0, but why should the measure of the union be 0? If $P_n$ is uncountable I can't use $\sigma$-additivity (same problem as before).

"Now just put it all together. Let $E'$ be the set of $x'$ such that $\mu(\mathcal P_n(x))=0$ for some $n$. This is another set of measure 0."

Again what happens if $E'$ is uncountable??

"Now if $x\in X\setminus(E\cup E')$, we're in business:
$\mu(\mathcal P_n(x))>0$ for all $n$ and $x$ returns to $\mathcal P_n(x)$ infinitely often. A diagonal argument finishes things off."

Okay $\mu(X\setminus(E\cup E'))=\mu(X)$ (for what I need $\mu(\mathcal P_n(x))>0$)?) 
We have sequences $(n_{m_k})$ such that $T^{m_k}(x) \in P_m(x)$.
Since $diam(P_n)\to 0$ it follows that $T^{n_{k_k}}(x)\to x$ for $k\to\infty$ (do I need compactness here?)

Comment: For the second question, we can let the partition $\mathcal P_n$ be a countable partition. For the fourth question, $\mu(\mathcal P_n(x))>0$ is needed for the statement $\{x:\mu(\mathcal P_{n+1}(x))>0\}\subset$\{x:\mu(\mathcal P_{n}(x))>0\}$ to make a diagonal argument. The first and third question is clear if you understand what a partition here means: we partition the space into disjoint measurable subsets such that the joint of them is the whole space up to a set of measure zero.

Comment: Thx for your answer. yeah I think the main problem is, that I don't understand how the partitioning works…:

Comment: Thx for your answer. yeah I think the main problem is, that I don't understand how the partitioning works…: I start covering X with open $\epsilon$-Balls around every X. Since X is compact I get a finite covering of X with diameter $\epsilon$. Now I cover each remaining $\epsilon$-ball with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$-balls and again I get a finite sub cover and the diameter of $P_2$ is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I continue and get the desired, countable sequence of partitions.

Comment: mhm with my process I don't get partitions because the sets are not disjoint…but this shouldn't be a problem or?